# the handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format in azure service bus queue

Tags: c#, azure

I have created a Microsoft Azure Namespace. Within it I created a service bus and queue.

Whenever I try to send the message to that queue from open network, the message get sent to queue successfully. But if I try to run the same code and send the message to queue in my company network, I'm getting the exception below -

Please find the code I used as below

```
            string messageContent = "msg";
            string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedSecretIssuer=owner;SharedSecretValue=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage(messageContent);
            QueueClient Client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "queuename");
            Client.Send(message);
```

Please help me here

Comment: Have you checked your company network allows outbound connections on the service bus ports? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee706729.aspx